# Is it possible to list a Dart class's parameters using dart:mirrors?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Let's say that I have a class `Person` defined like this:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  Person(this.name};
}
```

Is there any way to acquire a list of the class `Person`'s parameters using `dart:mirrors`. Basically, I'm working on a library that involves reflection, and I'd like to be able to create Booleans using a class's parameters, along the lines of:

```
bool hasParam(T t) ...
```

#### UPDATE

I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
var cm = reflectClass(Person);
print(cm.typeArguments);
```

When I run this, all that I get is an empty list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Person's parameters". Can you explain what it is you want to find for the Person class?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to find a way to generate the following list for the class: `List<String> personTypeArguments = ['name']`. Something along those lines. Or `['name','age','hobbies']` if those were the type arguments for the `Person` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClassMirror.typeArguments](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-mirrors.ClassMirror#id_typeArguments) to get a list of all type arguments for a type.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't seem to work for me. I'll modify my original question to show my steps.

Comment: "Type arguments" is usually used about the types passed to generic classes, e.g., for `new List<String>()` the type argument (also called "type parameter") is `String`.